# Swap workspace between two monitors on gnome

Tags: gnome3, multi-monitor, workspaces

I have two monitors and I am using gnome3.

I'd like to press a key so that the windows that are on monitor 1 appear on monitor 2 and those that were on monitor 2 go to monitor 1.
More concisely I'd like the two monitors to swap their workspaces.

Is there a command to do such a thing?